# Execute jar file in c#

Tags: c#

I have a problem with executing the jar file in c#.

This jar file is `epubcheck.jar`

here is my code to run the file

```
public string IdpfValidateEpub(string epub)
        {
            try
            {
                string result = null;

                string epubCheckPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "epubcheck.jar");
                string arguments = "java -jar" + " \"" + epubCheckPath + "\"" + " \"" + epub + "\"";
                System.Diagnostics.Process pProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

                //strCommand is path and file name of command to run
                pProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"cmd.exe";

                //strCommandParameters are parameters to pass to program
                pProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;

                Debug.WriteLine("arguments: " + pProcess.StartInfo.Arguments);

                pProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                pProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
                //Set output of program to be written to process output stream
                pProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

                //Start the process
                pProcess.Start();

                //Get program output
                result = pProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();



                //Wait for process to finish
                pProcess.WaitForExit();

                return result;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

But the program is not running at all. I also set the property to show the window. So i can see if its running or not. But it only shows the command prompt like this

[image]

I also printed the `arguments` i passed in the `System.Diagnostics.Process` in order to check if the arguments are correct.

After the program printed the arguments. i just copied it and paste in the command prompt. And the program works as expected. But why does it doesn't work in my c# code?

Thank you so much.

Comment: `java -jar` isn't an argument. `java` is the executable, `-jar` is the argument.

Comment: So instead of using cmd.exe i change my code into java?

Comment: Thank you it's working now. by simply changing the filename from cmd.exe into java

Answer (score 3):

Java is a program in its own right, so you don't actually need `cmd.exe` to run it.

Change your arguments to the following so that you're passing the arguments for `java`:

```
string arguments = "-jar" + " \"" + epubCheckPath + "\"" + " \"" + epub + "\"";
```

And then simply start `java` instead of `cmd`:

```
pProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"java";
```